# Adding Text Unexpectedly Pushing Container Down

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage that has two containers side by side and no gap in between. The container on the left occupies about 75% of the width while the container on the right occupies about 25%.

This is my current HTML and CSS code:

```
<!doctype html>

<style>
.container-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 850px; 
  height: 550px;
  background: #E5F2FD; 
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.welcome-message
{
    color: #026DBA;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Calibri";
}
.container-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px; 
  height: 550px; 
  background: #E5F2FD;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  text-align: center;   
}
</style>


<div class="container-left">

<p class="welcome-message"> Welcome back, Joe! </p>


</div><div class="container-right">

<p> Choose one... </p>

</div>


</html>
```

If you run this code, the addition of the p tag containing "Welcome back, Joe!" causes the container on the right to unexpectedly move downward. If you delete this line of code, however, the two containers go back to being inline with each other. I am wondering 1.) why this is the case and 2.) how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: So, I was going to move your code into an executable snippet, but unfortunately you have some foundational issues that need to be fixed first before we can start to tackle the issue you are seeing.  They are: **1)** Your code contains a closing `</html>` tag but no opening `<html>` tag **2)** You have not document [`<head />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) _nor_ a document [`<body />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body).  FWIW, you can generally omit this boilerplate in snippets, but they need to be present in your source code.

Comment: Also, removing them changed the rendered output in the snippet, so I opted not to make the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change them widths properties for max-width, a much better solution would be flexbox

```
<style>

.container {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.column-left {
flex: .75;
}

.column-right {
flex:.25;
}
</style>
<body class=“container”>
<div class=“column-left”></div>

<div class=“column-right”></div>

</body>
```

there are better examples out there, but basically you right container moves down because left container has a width of 75% so that means it has another  25% more to expand